# Report is taking hours to show the data and it returns 0 records

Tags: oracle, performance, time, where-clause

I have written a query using UNION functionality , but I'm not able to fetch any records. IT returns 0 records!!!

```
SELECT  
    p_mv.created_by                            createby, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(p_con.created_date,p_con.cdate_tz_code),'DD MON YY HH24:MI')  createdate,
    port.port_name                             dest, 
    p_con.pipeline_ref_id                      consolno, 
    reference_numbers.ref_num                  refnum, 
    route_s.vessel_name                        vessel, 
    route_s.flight_voyage                      voyage, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code),'DD/MM/YYYY')  destdate, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.arrival_date,route_s.arrival_date_tz_code),'DD/MM/YYYY') origindate, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code),'DD MON YY HH24:MI')  destdate, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.arrival_date,route_s.arrival_date_tz_code),'DD MON YY HH24:MI') origindate, 
    carrier.carrier_name                       carrier, 
    p_mv.pipeline_ref_id                       mawb, 
    sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code)  real_origindate ,
    DECODE(p_con.pipeline_tx_status,'O','OPEN','MFT','MANIFESTED','IS','ISSUED','CNF','CONFIRMED','OI','OPEN IMPORT','ICF','CONFIRM IMPORT','C','CLOSED','VD','VOID',p_con.pipeline_tx_status) status,
    cd_code.cd_description               consol_type



    from  pipeline             p_mv, 
    pipeline             p_con, 
    pipeline_relations   pr_cs, 
    route route_s , 
    reference_numbers, 
    carrier, 
    carrier_segment, 
    mwb_header ,
    consol ,
    port ,
    (SELECT cd_code,cd_description FROM  code_detail WHERE cm_code = '436') cd_code 

    where  (p_mv.pipeline_tx_id = pr_cs.pipeline_tx_id) AND 
    (p_mv.pipeline_tx_type = 'CS') AND 
    (pr_cs.rel_pipeline_tx_id = p_con.pipeline_tx_id(+)) AND    
    (pr_cs.rel_pipeline_tx_type(+) = 'CO' )  and 
    (p_con.pipeline_tx_id = consol.pipeline_tx_id) and 
    (p_mv.pipeline_tx_id = mwb_header.pipeline_tx_id(+)) and  
    (p_mv.pipeline_tx_id = reference_numbers.pipeline_tx_id(+)) and   
    (reference_numbers.ref_num_type(+) = 'CN') and  
    (p_mv.pipeline_tx_id = route_s.pipeline_tx_id(+)) and 
    (route_s.route_type(+) = 'S') and 
    (route_s.line_no(+) = 1) and 
    p_mv.pipeline_tx_id = carrier_segment.pipeline_tx_id(+) and 
    carrier_segment.carrier_code = carrier.carrier_code(+) and 
    p_con.port_dest = port.port_code(+) and 
    cd_code.cd_code(+) = consol.consol_service_type
    AND (p_con.orig_company_id ='570')
    AND (p_con.orig_terminal_id ='5705')
    AND p_con.pipeline_tx_status='CNF'
     AND mwb_header.transport_mode='O'

     and
/*Passing dates with the case statement to pass to different date abject at a time*/
    case '&psStatusType'
               when 'CTA' then p_con.created_date
               when 'VAD' then route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date
               when 'ETA' then route_s.arrival_date
               else null -- default anyway
          end 
          between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                  AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')




    UNION
    /*Using UNION functionality to join the query*/






    select
     p_con.created_by                            createby, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(p_con.created_date,p_con.cdate_tz_code),'DD MON YY HH24:MI')  createdate, 
    port.port_name                             dest, 
    p_con.pipeline_ref_id                      consolno, 
    ''                                         refnum, 
    route_s.vessel_name                        vessel, 
    route_s.flight_voyage                      voyage, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code),'DD/MM/YYYY')  destdate, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.arrival_date,route_s.arrival_date_tz_code),'DD/MM/YYYY') origindate, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code),'DD MON YY HH24:MI') destdate, 
    TO_CHAR(sf_get_local(route_s.arrival_date,route_s.arrival_date_tz_code),'DD MON YY HH24:MI') origindate, 
    carrier.carrier_name                       carrier, 
     ''                                         mawb, 
    sf_get_local(route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date,route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date_tz_code)  real_origindate ,
    DECODE(p_con.pipeline_tx_status,'O','OPEN','MFT','MANIFESTED','IS','ISSUED','CNF','CONFIRMED','OI','OPEN IMPORT','ICF','CONFIRM IMPORT','C','CLOSED','VD','VOID',p_con.pipeline_tx_status) status,
    cd_code.cd_description               consol_type 


    from pipeline p_con, 
    route route_s , 
    carrier, 
    consol ,
    port, 
    PIPELINE_RELATIONS PREL_CS, 
    (SELECT cd_code,cd_description FROM  code_detail WHERE cm_code = '436') cd_code



    where  (p_con.pipeline_tx_id = consol.pipeline_tx_id) and 
    P_CON.PIPELINE_TX_ID = PREL_CS.PIPELINE_TX_ID AND 
    PREL_CS.REL_PIPELINE_TX_TYPE ='CS' AND 
    (PREL_CS.REL_pipeline_tx_id = route_s.pipeline_tx_id(+)) and 
    (route_s.route_type(+) = 'S') and 
    (route_s.line_no(+) = 1) and 
    route_s.carrier_code = carrier.carrier_code(+) and 
    p_con.port_dest = port.port_code(+) and 
    cd_code.cd_code(+) = consol.consol_service_type and
    p_con.orig_company_id='570' and
    p_con.orig_terminal_id='5705'  and
    p_con.pipeline_tx_status='CNF' and
    consol.transport_mode = 'O'
     and

/*Passing dates with the case statement to pass to different date abject at a time*/
    case '&psStatusType'
               when 'CTA' then p_con.created_date
               when 'VAD' then route_s.orgn_vsl_arvl_date
               when 'ETA' then route_s.arrival_date
               else null -- default anyway
          end 
          between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                  AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Simplify your select and ensure that there are records to be returned. Do each side of the union by itself, removing all the tables that are outer joined. Remove one table at a time until you start returning records, and then add each table back one at a time. If you return no records after adding a table back, look at that particular join and why the data doesn't match up.

Comment: You are checking for `mwb_header.transport_mode = 'O'` in the first query of the union and checking for `consol.transport_mode = 'O'` in the second query. Is this intended?

You are also trying to outer join the `mwb_header` table in the first query, but are then forcing an inner join with this statement `mwb_header.transport_mode='O'`

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the 2nd query after UNION under where clause i have to add this condition: p_con.pipeline_ref_id not in (select p_con.pipeline_ref_id " + fc + wc + " ) FC mean from clause of first query and WC means where clause of first query. any idea?